# Meaning of a symbol

Tags: limits, notation

I've seen the symbol "$B_\epsilon(a)$", but I don't know what it means. The context is limits of a subsequence.  Here, $\epsilon>0$ is a real number, and the limit of subsequence $a_{n_k}$ is $a$, and $a_{n_k}\in B_\epsilon(a)$ is true for $k$ big enough.

Comment: It usually means hyper-sphere of radius $\varepsilon$ centered around $a$

Comment: @Ant: Hypersphere? No, I don't think so. It is an open ball, not a sphere -- these are mathematically distinct.

Comment: @MPW Well you're probably right, that is what I meant though. What is the difference then?

Comment: @Ant: It's like the difference between a circle and a disk. People often speak of a disk as a circle, but the circle is the outer edge only, and the interior would be the open ball (the "filling", if you will). Likewise, in 3 dimensions, the outer skin of the filled-in ball is a sphere, and the filling is an open ball. Note that the boundary of a n-dimensional ball is an (n-1)-dimensional sphere. Perhaps surprisingly, on the real line, an open ball is an open interval such as $(0,1)$, and the corresponding boundary is the pair of points $\left\{0,1\right\}$, so the 1-sphere is not connected.

Answer (score 2):

It seems  that it is a ball centered in $a$ of radius $\epsilon$: $B_\epsilon(a)=\{x: \|x-a\|<\epsilon\}$.

Comment: We're dealing with real numbers, so I would assume all the real numbers that are at distance smaller than $\epsilon$ from $a$?

Comment: @biz, for real numbers - yes. But you can define this notion for arbitrary metric spaces (in particular, for normed spaces, too).

Answer (score 1):

This is defined to be the “Ball around a with the radius $\epsilon$”:
$$B_\epsilon(a):=\{x\in V: d(x, v)<\epsilon\}$$
Where $(V, d)$ is a metric space. $V$ does not necessarily have to be normed.